# cron (reboot job) and wget (extract files) don't "get" along

Tags: python, linux, cron, raspberry-pi, wget

I'm trying really hard to get this to work, but I just can't seem to get it right.

I got this Raspberry Pi that I want to download photos from a dropbox link into a specific folder on reboot.

> sudo crontab -e

```
@reboot /home/pi/path/to/dir/with/photos/scripts.sh
```

> scripts.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
cd /home/pi/path/to/dir/with/photos/

# delete all photos and download and convert them again
rm -f /home/pi/crontab.refresh.log || true
sh /home/pi/path/to/dir/with/photos/refreshPhotos.sh > /home/pi/crontab.refresh.log

# convert all photos to bmp (and scale them)
rm -f /home/pi/crontab.convert.log || true
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/pi/path/to/dir/with/photos/convertPhotos.py > /home/pi/crontab.convert.log
```

> refreshPhotos.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# clear the "old" ones
rm -f *.JPG || true
rm -f *.jpg || true

# Get the "fresh" ones
wget -qO- https://www.dropbox.com/sh/AAA/BB -P /home/pi/path/to/dir/with/photos/ | bsdtar -xvf-
```

The `wget` looks a bit funky with the `-qO-` and `| bsdtar -xvf-` - it's in order avoid getting them into folder AAA and BBB.

Running the script from

```
/home/pi/path/to/dir$ bash /with/photos/scripts.sh
```

works just fine. BUT rebooting does not seem to work (it only deletes the old photos and does not download the new ones.

ANY help that will solve my issue will be highly appreciated!

Comment: For debugging purposes, put `sleep 30` before `sh /home/pi/path/to/dir/with/photos/refreshPhotos.sh`. Use `>& /home/pi/crontab.refresh.log`  in order to get stderr messages. And paste here any relevant messages.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion! It helped me find a solution. I have posted it as an answer so it can help others that are facing similiar issue.

Answer (score 0):

cron often starts a very basic shell with barely any environmental variables.
To make sure it gets the proper environment, follow this and add

`$HOME/.profile;`

to just before the command on @reboot, so

`@reboot $HOME/.profile; /home/pi/path/to/dir/with/photos/scripts.sh`

Answer from :[How can I run a cron command with existing environmental variables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27289/how-can-i-run-a-cron-command-with-existing-environmental-variables)

Comment: I was not using environmental variables, but thank you very much for trying to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

@Philippe suggestion helped me figuring out that it's because that the wifi connection is established once the cron job starts.

This did the trick:

> scripts.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
cd /home/pi/path/to/dir/with/photos/

# remove all old logs first
rm -f /home/pi/crontab.*.log || true
rm -f /home/pi/crontab.log || true

# delete all photos and download and convert them again
rm -f /home/pi/crontab.refresh.log || true
while ! ping -c1 dropbox.com >> /home/pi/crontab.wifi.log # Need to make sure that the internet connection is there before starting
  do echo "no connection to dropbox yet"
done
sh /home/pi/path/to/dir/with/photos/refreshPhotos.sh >& /home/pi/crontab.refresh.log
```

Thank you VERY much [@Philippe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2125671/philippe) !